# Inserting C# Datatable to sybase directly

Tags: c#, sybase

We need to read c# datatable and insert in to Sybase datatable. Without looping the rows.
Please suggest the ways to handle this (LINQ and normal).

Thanks,
Sai Korapati

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `AseDataAdapter` class from the Sybase C# client.